# Theorem about sum/product/quotient/composition of differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that a function sum/product/quotient/composition of differentiable functions is differentiable.

I have to find the subset $B $of the domain in which that theorem is applicable:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3 y \sqrt{|\sin(x^2+y^2)|}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

In an other point of the exercise, there is written "Check the existance of partial derivatives for the point of B $(x_0,0), (0, y_0)..$

I can't understand

1) why this subset doesn't correspond to the domain

2)why I can say that in  $(x_0,0), (0, y_0)$ f is not differentiable without doing the $$\lim_{\left(h,k\right)\rightarrow\left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x_{0}+h,y_{0}+k\right)-f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)h-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)k}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}=0.
 $$

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any theorem here.

Comment: @aev I'm sorry, I haven't understood.. what do you mean?

Comment: The domain of $|x|$ is $\mathbb R$, though it is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread you. I see what you mean now.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so, $x^2+y^2\neq k \pi$? I have edited the question, please, read it.. thanks!

Comment: This answers 1).